# MethodNotAllowedHttpException Error Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, routes

I have the error `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` when I submit form data using `ajax`.

**HTML**

```
<form class="form-signin" id="loginForm" role="form" method="POST">
    // Form
</form>
<script>
        $('#loginForm').submit(function () {
            initLogin($('#email').val(),$('#password').val());
        });
</script>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function initLogin(email, password) {

    $.ajax( {
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },  
        url:'loginModal',
        method:'POST',
        data: {
            strEmail: email,
            strPassword: password
        },  
        success: function( bolUpdated ) { 
            alert('yes');
        },  
        fail: function() {
             alert('no');
        }   
    }); 

}
```

**Route**

`Route::post( 'loginModal', 'Auth\LoginController@loginModal' );`

**Controller**

```
public function loginModal( Request $request ) { 
    Log::info('test');
}
```

I tried changing the form's type but no luck. Any idea what might be the issue?

Comment: I would try using postman or cURL to see if by any chance you are not hitting the URL you expect. It might make sense to just try a full url path in your ajax call for the moment to be more explicit.

Comment: Also try watching your network tab in your developer console to see what requests it's making.

Comment: Agree with @AlexHarris try to use PHP cURL to check the URL .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to stop the form from submitting if you're going t use ajax

```
    $('#loginForm').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); //<-- here 
        initLogin($('#email').val(),$('#password').val());
        return false; //<---- or here
    });
```

otherwise the form will make a post request to the current page(since action is not there) which has no route for a post request.

Answer (score 1):

prevent default event of form because you have not defined any action for form and its request is being sent to **current page**

```
 $('#loginForm').submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        initLogin($('#email').val(),$('#password').val());
    });
```